# Commit local files to different branches

Tags: git

Suppose I've made a checkout from branch `master`. There are 2 files there: `A` and `B`.

I have edited both of them, now I have files `A1` and `B1`. Suddenly I realized it would be a good idea to separate those changes in the following way:

- create `branchA` and commit `A1` there, but leave `B` unchanged. (branchA has A1 and B)
- create `branchB` and commit `B1` there, but leave `A` unchanged. (branchB has B1 and A)

How to achieve this with minimum effort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really do not have to stash.  Normally creating a new branch does not wipe away uncommitted changes.  So this should work:

```
git checkout -b branchA
git add A A1
git commit -m 'Changes in branchA.'
git checkout -b branchB HEAD~
git add B B1
git commit -m 'Changes in branchB.'
```

Comment: Don't I loose the changes in B1 file when resetting to HEAD~?

Comment: You do not lose your changes as it wasn't a reset.  It was creating a branch at a point.

Answer (score 1):

First add file A1 to be commited:

```
git add A1
```

the stash your modifications on B1:

```
git stash
```

then create and switch to branch `branchA` and commit modifications done on A1:

```
git checkout -b branchA
git commit -m "modification on A1"
```

then create an switch to branch `branchB` (beware: created from master) and apply your stash:

```
git checkout -b branchB master
git stash apply
git add B1
git commit -m "modification on B1"
```

Comment: Ha, I was also thinking stash will do the job

Comment: cforbish is right: `git stash` is not necessary. But after his answer, there is one thing I quite didn't understand well: did the file A changed and A1 is a newly created file ? Or A is unchanged and A1 is a modified copy of A (same for B/B1 of course) ?

Comment: I thought "A1" indicated "A (modified)"...  Whether A1 is or is not a new file, cforbush's method should work.

Comment: @Frodon  A is unchanged and A1 is a modified copy of A. Sorry for delay in answer